# How to set length of a combo box to only allow one of two values

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I have the combobox minLength set to 5. I want the combobox to require the length to be 5. If it is longer than 5, I want the minLength to be set to 10. So the outcome should be: the min length can be either 5 or 10, nothing else. (The ComboBox will not accept an input with a length of less than 5 or greater than 10, it also will not accept a length equal to 6, 7, 8, or 9).

Here is my code for example:

```
  xtype: 'combobox', 
  minLength: 5,
  maxLength: 10,
  maskRe: /[0-9.-]/,
  validator: function(v) {
    //this only allows numbers and a hyphen to be entered into the combo box,
    //while also requiring 4 digits to be entered after the hyphen 
    //(only if a hyphen is present)
    return /^[0-9]*(-?[0-9]{4})?$/.test(v)? true : 'A Postal Code should only include a hyphen if there are four digits after the hyphen!';
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no built-in solution for that, but you can do it. Check the code below and [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3ifm), this is for ExtJS 7.5 Classic Material, but it can likely be adopted to other version / toolkit.

Some notes:

- You have to set a `store`, even if it's empty, otherwise the `change` listener will not be called. (I don't know if it is a bug or a feature.)
- The solution uses a ViewModel and binds the `minLength` to this. The reason you need `setMinLength` and `setMaxLength` is that ExtJS doesn't provide it and getter / setter is required for binding.
- **Important**: since this is not an 'official' solution there is no guarantee it will always work.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',
    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: [{
                xtype: 'combo',
                minLength: 5,
                maxLength: 10,
                maskRe: /[0-9.-]/,
                viewModel: {
                    data: {
                        minLength: 5
                    }
                },
                store: [],
                bind: {
                    minLength: '{minLength}'
                },
                setMinLength: function (v) {
                    this.minLength = v;
                },
                getMinLength: function () {
                    return this.minLength;
                },
                validator: function (v) {
                    return /^[0-9]*(-?[0-9]{4})?$/.test(v) ? true : 'A Postal Code should only include a hyphen if there are four digits after the hyphen!';
                },
                listeners: {
                    change: function (combo, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
                        const newMinLength = newValue == null ? 5 : newValue.length >= 5 ? 10 : 5;
                        console.log('New min length will be: ' + newMinLength);
                        combo.getViewModel().set('minLength', newMinLength);
                    }
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Works as expected, thanks so much!

Comment: Good to hear, you are welcome!